# Reassign new hex value into Uint32 *

Tags: c, pointers, hex

I have the following code snippet which reads the pixel value in hex format.

```
Uint32* MyPixel = pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW;
printf("\npixelvalue is  is : %x",*MyPixel);
```

How can I reassign a new hex value into the *MyPixel cause I tried this does not work.

```
*MyPixel = "00FF00";
```

Comment: Use `*MyPixel = 0xFF00;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"00FF00"` is a string literal. You need a hex integer literal:

```
*MyPixel = 0x00FF00;
```

Prefix `0x` tells the compiler that the rest of the numeric literal needs to be interpreted as a numeric hex constant.

Comment: ok it works but unfortunatelly the pixel is not changing it values never mind let me look into it.

Comment: @Actually kevin its based on SDL codes so the mypixl is pointing to the structure consist of all the pixels

Comment: Note that you're assigning a value to an 'uninitialized' variable as it does not point to any memory space.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Why is it not initialized? If `pixels` points to an array of pixels of the size larger than `( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW`, then `pixels + ( (iH-1) + image->w ) + iW` points to a valid place in memory.

Comment: Oops, got it. I read it wrong in that he wanted to just do the value  assignation `*MyPixel = 0xff00;`without the allocation.....